# Ruby - How to find Customer with nested join

Tags: ruby, postgresql

I have the following relationships:

```
class Location < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :weddings

class Wedding < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :wedding_memberships

class WeddingMembership < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :wedding
  belongs_to :customer

class Customer < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :wedding_memberships
```

And what I would like to find is the `Customer`s in `Location` with `id: 1`

My attempts `WeddingMembership.joins(:wedding).where(wedding: {location_id: 1})` are giving me the following errors: `Caused by PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "wedding"`

Comment: `WeddingMembership.joins(:wedding).where(weddings: {location_id: 1})`, `weddings`, there you need the name of the table

Comment: @Ursus that does work, however its returning `WeddingMemberships` when I need `Customers`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one, it's a multiple join with a where clause on your `location_id`

```
Customer.joins(wedding_memberships: :wedding)
        .where(weddings: { location_id: 1 })
        .distinct
```

Comment: Yea I was going there too.. but when I try that I get `ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Can't join 'Customer' to association named 'wedding'; perhaps you misspelled it?`

Comment: Are you sure you tried with my same `joins` clause? If your associations are right this should work

Comment: I think you missed the `wedding_memberships` in the `joins` clause

Comment: Ahhhh, I didn't do this `(wedding_memberships: :wedding)` correctly.. thanks so much!

Comment: I probably missed a `distinct` in the end